# git move folder one level down and maintain history

Tags: git

I want to move:

`./frontend` to `./frontend/application`

But when I do `git mv -v * ./application` from `./frontend`

I get this error:

> fatal: can not move directory into itself,
>   source=frontend/application,
>   destination=frontend/application/application

But when I do `mv -v * ./application` I get the result I expect.

Comment: In doubt, move twice: `/foo` to `/bar`, and `/bar` to `/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing `git mv -v * ./application`, the `*` is expanded as all the files in the current folder, `application` included.
Git doesn't like to move a folder into itself, but `mv` handle it fine.

You have 2 solutions:

1. Exclude `application` when using `git mv`:

   ```
   git mv -v !(application) application # in bash
   ```
2. Move on the filesystem, then index with git:

   ```
   mv -v * application
   git add .
   # Git will detect the move
   ```